# Elegantly populate dictionary from a struct checking nil values

Tags: swift, dictionary

Given a struct `A`, I want to populate a `NSDictionary` with values from that struct, provided they are not nil. 
 
To do that I insert all the values and then loop through the dictionary removing all `nil`. Is there a more elegant, concise, and less brute-force solution?

```
struct A {
    var first:String?
    var second:String?
    var third:String?

    /* some init */
}

let a = A(/*some init*/)

var dictionary = [
    "first":a.first,
    "second":a.second,
    "third":a.third
]

for (key,value) in dictionary {
    if value == nil {
        dictionary.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually not a good idea to have a dictionary with a value that is optional.  Dictionaries use the assignment of `nil` as an indication that you want to delete a key/value pair from the dictionary.  Also, dictionary lookups return an optional value, so if your value is optional you will end up with a double optional that needs to be unwrapped twice.

You can use the fact that assigning `nil` deletes a dictionary entry to build up a `[String : String]` dictionary by just assigning the values.  The ones that are `nil` will not go into the dictionary so you won't have to remove them:

```
struct A {
    var first: String?
    var second: String?
    var third: String?
}

let a = A(first: "one", second: nil, third: "three")

let pairs: [(String, String?)] = [
    ("first", a.first),
    ("second", a.second),
    ("third", a.third)
]

var dictionary = [String : String]()

for (key, value) in pairs {
    dictionary[key] = value
}

print(dictionary)
```

> ```
> ["third": "three", "first": "one"]
> ```

As @Hamish noted in the comments, you can use a `DictionaryLiteral` (which internally is just an array of tuples) for `pairs` which allows you to use the cleaner dictionary syntax:

```
let pairs: DictionaryLiteral<String,String?> = [
    "first":  a.first,
    "second": a.second,
    "third":  a.third
]
```

All of the other code remains the same.

Note:  You can just write `DictionaryLiteral` and let the compiler infer the types, but I have seen Swift fail to compile or compile very slowly for large dictionary literals.  That is why I have shown the use of explicit types here.

---

Alternatively, you can skip the `Array` or `DictionaryLiteral` of `pairs` and just assign the values directly:

```
struct A {
    var first: String?
    var second: String?
    var third: String?
}

let a = A(first: "one", second: nil, third: "three")

var dictionary = [String : String]()

dictionary["first"] = a.first
dictionary["second"] = a.second
dictionary["third"] = a.third

print(dictionary)
```

> ```
> ["third": "three", "first": "one"]
> ```

Comment: You could also use a `DictionaryLiteral` instead of a `[(String, String?)]` – e.g `let pairs: DictionaryLiteral = ["first" : a.first, "second" : a.second, "third" : a.third]`.

Comment: @Hamish, you could do that.  Since I'm just accessing them as pairs, it seemed more straightforward to make it an array of tuple pairs.  Also, I've see that if you make Swift infer the type of a large dictionary literal, it can be slow or fail to ever compile.  I think if you are going to use a dictionary here it should be explicitly typed as `[String : String?]` to save the compiler the effort.

Comment: You can explicitly annotate the type of the `DictionaryLiteral` – `DictionaryLiteral<String, String?>`, which should "save the compiler the effort" :) It's worth noting that a `DictionaryLiteral` is nothing more than an array of tuples under the hood, the only reason I suggested it was for a slight syntactic improvement (the ability to use a dictionary literal).

Comment: @Hamish.  Thanks, `DictionaryLiteral` is interesting.  It allows duplicate keys and is ordered.

Answer (score 1):

As [@vacawama says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43356881/2976878), you should generally steer clear of `Dictionary` types with optional values, as the `Dictionary` API is built around using `nil` to indicate the lack of a value for a given key. Therefore using an optional type for a `Dictionary`'s `Value` results in confusing double-wrapped optionals, which can often exhibit unintuitive behaviour.

Another (more overkill) solution would be to directly utilise dictionary literals by defining your own 'value unwrapping' `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral` type.

```
extension Dictionary {

    /// A dictionary wrapper that unwraps optional values in the dictionary literal
    /// that it's created with.
    struct ValueUnwrappingLiteral : ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {

        typealias WrappedValue = Dictionary.Value

        fileprivate let base: [Key : WrappedValue]

        init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (Key, WrappedValue?)...) {

            var base = [Key : WrappedValue]()

            // iterate through the literal's elements, unwrapping the values,
            // and updating the base dictionary with them.
            for case let (key, value?) in elements {

                if base.updateValue(value, forKey: key) != nil {
                    // duplicate keys are not permitted.
                    fatalError("Dictionary literal may not contain duplicate keys")
                }
            }

            self.base = base
        }
    }

    init(unwrappingValues literal: ValueUnwrappingLiteral) {
        self = literal.base // simply get the base of the unwrapping literal.
    }
}
```

You can then simply pass instances of this type to our `init(unwrappingValues:)` initialiser:

```
struct A {
    var first: String?
    var second: String?
    var third: String?
}

let a = A(first: "foo", second: nil, third: "baz")

let dictionary = Dictionary(unwrappingValues: [
    "first"  : a.first,
    "second" : a.second,
    "third"  : a.third
])

print(dictionary) // ["third": "baz", "first": "foo"]
```