# Create a Dictionary from optionals

Tags: swift, dictionary

I some optionals: `numberOfApples:Int?`, `numberOfBananas:Int?`, `numberOfOlives:Int?` and I'd like to create a dictionary of just the set values. Is there way do succinctly create this?

The closest I've got is:

```
// These variables are hard-coded for the example's
// sake. Assume they're not known until runtime.

let numberOfApples: Int? = 2
let numberOfBananas: Int? = nil
let numberOfOlives: Int? = 5

let dict: [String:Int?] = ["Apples"  : numberOfApples,
                              "Bananas" : numberOfBananas,
                              "Olives"  : numberOfOlives]
```

And I'd like to dict to be of type: [String:Int] like so:

```
["Apples" : 2,
 "Olives" : 5]
```

But this gives me a dictionary of optionals and accessing a value by subscripting gives my a double-wrapped-optional.

I realise that I could do this with a for-loop, but I was wondering if there's something more elegant.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you want it to be [String: String] but your example has [String: Int]

Comment: A dictionary with optional values is nonsensical because it defeats the dictionary rule that a `nil` value means *key is missing*. And do you really need *maybe-number-of-something*? Practically *no apples* is `numberOfApples = 0`

Comment: @Yannick Thanks – My mistake. See the updated question.

Comment: @vadian You're correct. This is only an example but I do have a case in which I need a dictionary of only set values.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/43356680/2976878 (dupe?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would do it this way (and it's how I personally do this when it comes up):

```
var dict: [String: Int] = [:]
dict["Apples"] = numberOfApples
dict["Bananas"] = numberOfBananas
dict["Olives"] = numberOfOlives
```

Simple. Clear. No tricks.

But if you wanted to, you could write `Dictionary.flatMapValues` (to continue the pattern of `Dictionary.mapValues`). It's not hard. (EDIT: Added `flattenValues()` to more closely match original question.)

```
extension Dictionary {
    func flatMapValues<T>(_ transform: (Value) throws -> T?) rethrows -> [Key: T] {
        var result: [Key: T] = [:]
        for (key, value) in self {
            if let transformed = try transform(value) {
                result[key] = transformed
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    func flattenValues<U>() -> [Key: U] where Value == U? {
        return flatMapValues { $0 }
    }
}
```

With that, you could do it this way, and that would be fine:

```
let dict = [
    "Apples" : numberOfApples,
    "Bananas": numberOfBananas,
    "Olives" : numberOfOlives
    ].flattenValues()
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have this method unless constrained by `where Value == Optional<T>`, does it?

Comment: Why does it have to be constrained? This maps any method that returns an optional. So it works the same for an `init?`. Consider `["Apples": "1", "Bananas": "x"].flatMapValues(Int.init)`. That will create a dictionary of any pairs where the value can be converted to an Int. `flatMap` is a general solution; not just a "remove nils" method.

Comment: Hm. Yes you're right there. Your solution is more generic. However, since the question was "How do I turn `[String: Int?]` into `[String: Int]`", I'd _personally_ prefer my option, because it does exactly that without the user having to reason about an additional parameter (closure) to do what he wants. Nevertheless, your version is quite more elegant (I love the `Int.init` example :)). Both are going in to my `GlobalFunctions.swift` :D

Comment: Updated to include `flattenValues` to apply the `.flatMap{$0}`. Yeah… sometimes that syntax is a little nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` and `mapValues`. You first `filter` all pairs where the value is not nil and then you can safely force unwrap the value. This will change the dict type to `[String: Int]`.

```
let dict = [
        "Apples": numberOfApples,
        "Bananas": numberOfBananas,
        "Olives": numberOfOlives
    ]
    .filter({ $0.value != nil })
    .mapValues({ $0! })
print(dict) //["Olives": 5, "Apples": 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question before I'd fixed it! What @MartinR mentions remains though — I am trying to get a single dictionary.

Comment: @MartinR You are right, sorry. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let numberOfApples: Int? = 5
let numberOfBananas: Int? = nil
let numberOfOlives: Int? = 5

let dict: [String: Int?] = [
  "Apples": numberOfApples,
  "Bananas": numberOfBananas,
  "Olives": numberOfOlives
]

extension Dictionary {
    func flatMapValues<U>() -> [Key: U] where Value == Optional<U> {
        return reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value }
        // Keeping this line as it provides context for comments to this answer. You should delete it if you copy paste this.
        // return filter { $0.value != nil } as! [Key : U]
    }
}

let unwrappedDict = dict.flatMapValues()

let foo: Int?? = dict["Apples"]
let bar: Int? = unwrappedDict["Apples"]
```

Comment: (got it) <strike>The problem with this approach is that it leads to nested Optionals (as you're seeing with `foo` being `Int??`). Nested optionals are difficult to work with and are usually a mistake. IMO any good solution here will return a `[String: Int]`.</strike>

Comment: @RobNapier: `unwrappedDict` *is* a `[String: Int]` here.

Comment: The nested Optional comes from dict being of type `[X: Optional<Y>]`. Dictionary subscripts always return `Optional<Value>`. `withSafelyUnwrappedValues()` turns subscript return values from `<Optional<Optional<Value>>` into `Optional<Value>`

Comment: The forced cast `as! [Key : U]` is scary however, it would be nice to avoid that.

Comment: Yeah; I'm kind of shocked that even works. I didn't realize you could use `as!` to replace `!`. Is it really defined to do that across a dictionary? Is it promised that `T` and `T?` have the same memory layout? (or is there a special case to rewrite the dictionary?)

Comment: @RobNapier: I was surprised as well, but `let x: [Int: Int?] = [1: 2]; let y = x as! [Int: Int]` works. I don't know if that is guaranteed. It must be a conversion because `T` and `T?` usually have different memory layout (classes and pointers are an exception)

Comment: better to use reduce into `return reduce(into: [Key: U](), { if let value = $1.value { $0[$1.key] = value } })}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. This gets rid of `as!`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @MartinR It's indeed a conversion, and it's the same conversion that allows  `var i: Int? = 4; let unwrapped = i as! Int` to succeed. `Dictionary` casts (well, conversions really) are done through the stdlib function [`_dictionaryDownCastConditional`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/111499d2bfc58dc12fcb9cd1ce1dda7978c995b7/stdlib/public/core/HashedCollections.swift.gyb#L2977) (which the runtime calls into). This just does an iteration over the dict doing `as?` casts on the keys + values....

Comment: ...Optional casting is handled primarily in the runtime function [`checkDynamicCastFromOptional`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1efc07b9442f26cd2529e4d1bfc5df25d5a6b70a/stdlib/public/runtime/Casting.cpp#L2001), which notes for the `.some` case: "*Single payload enums are guaranteed layout compatible with their payload.*", so presumably for cases where the size of `Optional<T>` != size of `T`, the trailing descriminant bits are just truncated. So long story short; yup, it looks like it's guaranteed behaviour.

Comment: @LeoDabus The `if let` is unnecessary – `reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value }` :)

Comment: @Hamish: I wonder why _dictionaryDownCastConditional has the precondition that "... all of these types are reference types". That would not apply to a [Int, Int?] dictionary.

Comment: @MartinR Hah, good spot. Looks like a legacy comment [from the days where dictionary casting really did only work with references](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/435a8ddf0c4e7b1e85d367d1d9819439978ae284/stdlib/core/Dictionary.swift#L2270) (as it was just unsafely casting stuff). Taking a look at the IR emitted for a conditional cast from `[Int: Int?]` to `[Int: Int]` reveals that `_dictionaryDownCastConditional` is called for it though; so the precondition definitely doesn't apply.